# Need help with really simple regular expression

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am using PHP to match the following data type :

```
[["1200","135"],["127","13"]]
```

I want to extract all the numbers into a seperate array of arrays like this :

```
array(array(1200,135),array(127,13));
```

I am using preg_match to capture the elements but so far i am not even able to match them against a rule.
I will gladly appreciate if someone can help me correct my rule or even provide a solution as to how to accomplish this.

My regex rule is : `/    ^[          (["  (\d+)  ","  (\d+)  "])*(,)*               ]$    /`

**I've kept it unescaped to make it more readable on this forum**. However it doesn't work.
Please help

Comment: Still, how do i check if the data given matches the syntax ? I mean, if someone introduces a comma or additional orphan square bracket [ how do i check it using regex ?

Comment: You don't. What for? If this is a JSON string, then just run it through `json_decode` and if it doesn't return NULL it's valid.

Comment: Okay, but can you tell me whats wrong with my regular expression ?

Comment: Regular expressions are generally not the best tool for processing nested structures...recognizing matched parentheses is the classic example of a task that cannot be done with (pure) regular expressions.  Many programming languages extend pure regular expressions in ways that let them recognize context-free or more complex languages, but even so, using a more powerful parsing method can get rid of a lot of heartburn and headaches.

Comment: could you please review the answers to this and your previous questions and either accept the most helpful ones or edit your questions to point out why none of the answers solve your question. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try

```
var_dump( json_decode('[["1200","135"],["127","13"]]') );
```

gives:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=> array(2) {
    [0]=> string(4) "1200"
    [1]=> string(3) "135"
  }
  [1]=> array(2) {
    [0]=> string(3) "127"
    [1]=> string(2) "13"
  }
}
```

See PHP Manual:

- [`json_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) — Decodes a JSON string

Answer (score 3):

A few mistakes in your regexp are: using start and end anchors (^ and $) and not escaping the square brackets.

But **do use json_decode()**, that's what it's for.

Answer (score 1):

Quite easy:

```
  $proper = '[["1200","135"],["127","13"]]';
  $nuked = '[["1200",,"135"],[["127","13"]]';
  $pattern = '/[["[0-9]*","[0-9]*"],["[0-9]*?","[0-9]*"]]/s';
  echo "proper: ". preg_match($pattern, $proper);
  echo "<br>";
  echo "nuked: ". preg_match($pattern, $nuked);
```

Outputs:

```
proper: 1
nuked: 0
```

Pretty much it has to look exactly as you have given it except the data between the `"` can change. I hope this is what you wanted?

Comment: According to that regex, this string is well formed: `",""],[",""]]`

Comment: It appears it does, I didn't really test it that much as I much prefer to avoid regex as it seems like a really inelegant solution to any problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are processing JSON, so use json decode, like this :

```
php > print_r(json_decode('[["1200","135"],["127","13"]]'));
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1200
            [1] => 135
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 127
            [1] => 13
        )

)
```